# How to get the name of a placemark using google earth api?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I'm trying to create a web page where an user could manage diferent placemark. The management is based on create, drag and drop and delete placemarks. At the moment, I've achieved to create multiple placemarks and drag&drop them but I'm not able to delete it because I cannot identify them individually. I'm using the google earth api examples[1](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?#creating_placemarks) but I cannot find this functionality. I want to get the name of the different placemarks, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you want here, but it sounds like you'd like to walk through the placemarks and get their names.  To do that, you can loop through the features in your Google Earth plugin using the list of features returned by 
           var kmlnodes = ge.getFeatures().getChildNodes();

where ge is your google earth instance.  You can then call getType on each node in the list to determine which ones are placemarks.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign each placemark an ID and then refer to it later using that:

`var placeMark = ge.createPlacemark('uniqueID');`

Then you can retrieve the placemark later using `getElementByUrl()` if it was created/imported using KML with the API or `getElementById()` if created with the API and KML was not used:

`var placeMark = ge.getElementByUrl('#' + uniqueID)`

`var placeMark = ge.getElementById(uniqueID)`